# Do I need a visa to enter Romania if I have an EEA residence permit?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, paperwork, romania

I have an Indian passport. I used to have a Romanian residence permit, which has expired. Now, I have an EEA family permit for five years issued by the UK. I am living with my Romanian wife and son in London, and we all want to go visit Romania, but first my wife and son will be leaving. After they have left, I want to travel alone for only 8 days from Heathrow Airport. Do I need to first apply for a Romanian visa for entry, or I can go with my valid passport and EEA residence permit?
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you have a [residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card)?  The [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit) is issued for six months.

Comment: Please upload a copy of your residence Permit, blacking out personal details

Comment: My residence card issued for five years

Answer (score 2):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a family member residence card issued by
>     Switzerland or another EEA Member State. The
>     card must be issued to family members of a national of
>     Switzerland or an EEA Member State. They are
>     visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days and must travel
>     with **or travel to join the national of Switzerland or EEA
>     Member State.**

So no, you do **not** need a visa for Romania. However, you need to bring proof (phone number, other documentation) that your Family is in Romania and that you will join them.

Comment: I have dat first one residence permit family member-EU RESIDENCE so can I travel alone to romania

Comment: @user9771 You must travel to join your family members, which you will do because they're travelling first. Bring documentation proving they're there and are waiting for you